# Getting Function Evaluation Timedout error when using function inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to query an object and create anonymous type from the result. I am using a function inside the linq query. At this stage i am getting an error saying "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function..."

Please find below my sample code.

```
var serviceResult = _service.GeResponse(panId, numberOfTransactions, startDate, endDate);

var balanceTrans = GetAllTypes<BalanceAdjustment>(serviceResult);
var presentmentTrans = GetAllTypes<Presentment>(serviceResult);

var test = balanceTrans.AsEnumerable();
var obj = test.Select(item => new SearchCardTransactionResult
{
    PanId = item.PanId,
    CardNumber = item.CardNumberFormatted,
    Balance = item.FinancialBalance,
    BillingAmount = Math.Abs(item.BillingAmount).Format(),
    BillingCurrency = GetCurrencyCode(item.BillingCurrency)
});


private IList<T> GetAllTypes<T>(GetTransactionsResponse result)
    where T : ValitorServices.ValitorPanWS.AbstractFinancialTransaction
{
    return result.FinanacialTransactions.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Could anyone advice what am i doing wrong here?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve by using the following code.

```
var currencyCodes = _service.GetCurrencyCodes().ToList();
var test = balanceTrans.AsEnumerable();

    var obj = test.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new SearchCardTransactionResult
    {
        PanId = item.PanId,
        CardNumber = item.CardNumberFormatted,
        Balance = item.FinancialBalance,
        BillingAmount = Math.Abs(item.BillingAmount).Format(),
        BillingCurrency = currencyCodes.First(c=>c.NumericCode.Equals(item.BillingCurrency)).AlphabeticCode
    });
```